# Twilio Python helper library - How do you know how many pages list resource returned?

Tags: python, twilio

I'm trying to write a simple script to download call details information from Twilio using the python helper library. So far, it seems that my only option is to use .iter() method to get every call ever made for the subaccount. This could be a very large number.

If I use the .list() resource, it doesn't seem to give me a page count anywhere, so I don't know for how long to continue paging to get all calls for the time period. What am I missing?

Here are the docs with code samples:
http://readthedocs.org/docs/twilio-python/en/latest/usage/basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the above code did not work because remaining_messages = client.calls.count() always returns 50, making it absolutely useless for paging.

Instead, I ended up just trying next page until it fails, which is fairly hacky. The library should really include numpages in the list resource for paging.

```
import twilio.rest
import csv

account = <ACCOUNT_SID>
token = <ACCOUNT_TOKEN>

client = twilio.rest.TwilioRestClient(account, token)

csvout = open("calls.csv","wb")
writer = csv.writer(csvout)

current_page = 0
page_size = 50
started_after = "20111208"

test = True

while test:

     try:
         calls_page = client.calls.list(page=current_page, page_size=page_size, started_after=started_after)

         for calls in calls_page:
             writer.writerow( (calls.sid, calls.to, calls.duration, calls.start_time) )

         current_page += 1
     except:
         test = False
```

Comment: The incorrect count was a temporary API regression that is now fixed. The original code should work now.

Comment: Well, yes it's fixed, but if you think about what it's returning you will likely see the issue I have with it. For one subaccount I was querying it returned 338452, whereas the result set for the specific range and criteria I was looking for is around 96000. If I used the specified method, I would end up trying to page though an additional 242,000 entries that I never actually requested. The prescribed algorithm for paging is only suitable for the complete dataset, not a filtered one. Let me know if it doesn't make sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It's not very well documented at the moment, but you can use the following API calls to page through the list:

```
import twilio.rest
client = twilio.rest.TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)
# iterating vars
remaining_messages = client.calls.count()
current_page = 0
page_size = 50 # any number here up to 1000, although paging may be slow...
while remaining_messages > 0:
     calls_page = client.calls.list(page=current_page, page_size=page_size)
     # do something with the calls_page object...
     remaining_messages -= page_size
     current_page += 1
```

You can pass in `page` and `page_size` arguments to the `list()` function to control which results you see. I'll update the documentation today to make this more clear.

Comment: Are you able to pass date arguments?

Comment: Yes, as ended_after, ended_before, ended, started_before, started_after, or started, as datetime objects. Here is the function implementation: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/blob/master/twilio/rest/resources.py#L610

Comment: Well, unfortunately client.calls.count() always returns 50... so this code does not work.

Comment: Hi Sologoub, It looks like you've found a bug in our API, which is not correctly returning the total number of calls associated with an account. We are working on a fix now and our API should be reporting the correct number soon.

Comment: Kevin, that might be the case, but I would still suggest a change to the library. It makes no sense to me to have to page through based on total count of the calls (which can be in the millions). Paging should be done on the "numpages" attribute: http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response#response-formats-list

Comment: Hi Sologoub,  It should be fixed now - can you verify this for your account? I haven't checked it, but you should be able to modify the above example to use the num_pages attribute.