# Twilio API times out on client.calls.count(), does not accept "started_after" parameter

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate through a list of calls made from a certain date using Twilio's python library. However, whenever I call

```
client.calls.count()
```

I get an error 500 which appears to be a timeout:

```
twilio.TwilioRestException: HTTP ERROR 500: 20500: An internal server error has occurred
```

So I tried to get a count of calls for the time range I am interested in, as follows:

```
calls = client.calls.list(started_after=date(year, month, day))
```

Where year, month and day are ints. But this gets me an error:

```
TypeError: count() got an unexpected keyword argument 'started_after'
```

What's up? How can I get a count of calls from a certain date? I am trying to follow what is described here: [Twilio Python helper library - How do you know how many pages list resource returned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392491/twilio-python-helper-library-how-do-you-know-how-many-pages-list-resource-retu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly this is something that happens when your data grows too large - we can't return the count() fast enough and the query times out. We're working on a fix but it is a ways out still.

You may want to try using the [Usage Record API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/usage-records) for usage information like the number of calls, etc. You can filter the usage record data by arbitrary date times.

Otherwise, you can retrieve all of your results, following the `next_page_uri` provided by Twilio (or the iterator in Python) and keep a count as you go. Sorry I can't give you a better answer :(